# Angular nvd3 shows gaps between bars of grouped chart

Tags: angular-nvd3

I have a scenario where i need to show top 5 values for each date (each date data may differ). 
Issue scenario : For date 10th sep i have got response (top 5 -> Samsung Electronics, Lg, Apple, Amazon, Murata) now for the next day i.e 11th sep i have got response (top 5 -> Samsung electronics, Apple, Amazon, Murata, Other)....
Now if you notice then 2nd position of 10th sep data (Lg) is not present in 11th sep data.

In this case while plotting graph by default nvd3 keeps a blank space for "Lg" on 11th sep which must not be shown.
Screenshots are attached[image]

How to resolve this issue?